# How to render a plot.ly Jupyter Notebook file into Dash python Dashboard

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to have you sharing the template in Dash python where it generate a scatter charter with the help of plot.ly stunning graphics.
I am unable to make my Dash framework running but I do the same flawlessly in Jupyter Notebook. Just was wondering if I could run it on Dash.

Your help is much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: include your code so that someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Kanan for the tip. I will add it asap.

Comment: I have solved it. How to mark it has solved?

Comment: Answer your own question and make it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.
It was due to miscoding. The code was not in the right place.
Thanks.